# Mark Outlook 2016 messages as read on specific folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following macro in ThisOutlookSession on Outlook 2016:

```
Private WithEvents g_OlkFolder As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set g_OlkFolder = olNs.Folders.Item("[myaccount]").Folders.Item("enviadas").Items
End Sub
Private Sub g_OlkFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   Item.UnRead = False
   Item.Save
End Sub
```

The code is working, but is working for all folders under Inbox, including itself. In other words: the code is marking messages as read on "enviadas" folder but also on "Inbox" folder.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is that a PST store? Do you have a rule that moves items from the Inbox to ta subfolder?

Comment: Yes. It is a PST store. But the rule move the sent messages to that subfolder. The message is not saved into 'Sent Items' but is moved to "enviadas" subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler and the rule can conflict. And under the PST store provider, message entry ids do not change when an item is moved to a different folder, which means your code (or the rule) can successfully modify the message even if it was already moved to a different folder.

Also, there is no reason to call Item.Save - setting the Unread property does nto require that (it is not part of the message).

Comment: But a message that arrives into Inbox will also be marked as read?

Comment: In your ItemAdd event handler, add a line like "MsgBox Item.Parent.Name". What does it show?

Comment: Sorry! It was a rule that was marking my message as read. I will mark your answer as correct.